# Using the PropertyDescriptor can I determine if a property is overridden in the current class

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

If I have:

```
class A
{
    public virtual string Owner { get; set; }
}

class B : A
{
    public override string Owner { get; set; }
}
```

How do I determine that owner property on class `B` is an override property using the `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type)` method?

Comment: The answer you linked to uses type.GetProperties not TypeDescriptor.GetProperties. I am looking for an answer that uses PropertyDescriptor to determine an override.

Comment: I found a difference if you dig into: `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(t).Find("Owner", false).ComponentType.GetProperty("Owner").GetMethod.Attributes`. A has `VtableLayoutMask` but B doesn't. It doesn't seem conclusive enough as an answer, but it might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @DaveShaw's comment and the answers for similar questions using propertyInfo :

```
var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(B)).Find("Owner", false).ComponentType.GetProperty("Owner");
var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(false);
bool isOverride = getMethod.GetBaseDefinition() != getMethod;
```